# Easy Limit 2 Variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Does the following limit exists?
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to \ (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin(xy^3)}{\sqrt{x^8-y^6}} $$

Comment: If we only consider points in the domain, have you considered what happens for a fixed $x\in(0,1)$ as $y\to x^{(8/6)}$?

Comment: Why do you call it *easy* and ask the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the function restricted to the points of its domain $(x,0)$ you get immediately that the limit is $0$. But if restrict the function to the points of the type $(x,y)$ with $y(x)=x^{4/3}-x^4$ which belong to the domain (at least for |x| small enough) you obtain that
$$
f\left( {x,y(x)} \right) = \frac{{x^4  + o(x^4 )}}{{\sqrt 6 x^{{\textstyle{{16} \over 3}}}  + o\left( {x^{{\textstyle{{16} \over 3}}} } \right)}}
$$
and you get
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f\left( {x,y(x)} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x^4  + o(x^4 )}}{{\sqrt 6 x^{{\textstyle{{16} \over 3}}}  + o\left( {x^{{\textstyle{{16} \over 3}}} } \right)}} =  + \infty 
$$
Hence the limit of your function does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find two sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x'_n,y'_n)$ such that  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n,y_n) \not= \lim_{n\to \infty}f(x'_n,y'_n).$$
Let $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,0)$ to make outer limit zero. Now let's think intuitively when such limit can be big? It is natural to asked what hapen near curve $x^8=y^6$ (as it was pointed out in Joe's comment). So it is natural to check $(x'_n,y'_n)=(1/n,1/n^{4/3}-1/n^{10})$ when $1/n^{10}$ stands for just little negligible perturbation. After necessary but rutin calculation $$f(x'_n,y'_n)=\frac{\sin \Big({\color{red}{\frac{1}{n^5}}}-\frac{1}{n^{31}}-\frac{3}{n^{41/3}}+\frac{3}{n^{67/3}}\Big)}{\sqrt{\color{red}{\frac{6}{n^{50/3}}}-\frac{1}{n^{60}}-\frac{15}{n^{76/3}}-\frac{15}{n^{128/3}}+\frac{6}{n^{154/3}}+\frac{20}{n^{34}}}},$$
where I marked the leading terms. Therefore $$f(x'_n,y'_n) \approx \frac{\frac{1}{n^5}}{\frac{\sqrt{6}}{n^{50/6}}}=\frac{n^{10/3}}{\sqrt{6}}\to \infty.$$
PS The calculation was quite messy however I with premeditation take weird perturbation $1/n^{10}$ just to show intention of being closer and closer to curv $x^8=y^6$. There is a great chance to do this task easier way. It is worth to check some different perturbations $1/n^{\alpha}$ or even change variables to polar.